# Confirm remote sync - Firebase Realtime Database w/ ReactJS+Redux+Saga

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, redux-saga

I have a ReactJS/Redux/Saga app which currently sends and reads data from a Firebase Realtime Database. As data is sent and received, there's a global redux state value `loading`, which toggles between `true` and `false` between sending data and confirming that data is now in Firebase. `loading` defaults to `false` for this case.

When a user updates their data, the flow is currently:

- Redux reducer `SEND_TO_FIREBASE`

`return { ...state, loading: true };`

- This reducer triggers a Saga function `sendToFirebaseSaga()`

```
     function* syncToFirebaseSaga({ payload: userData }) {
        try {
            var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            const database = (path, payload) => {
                firebase
                    .database()
                    .ref(path)
                    .set(payload);
            };
            yield call(database, "users/" + uid + "/userData", userData);
            yield console.log("successfully written to database");
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }
```

- So, at this point `loading:true` (confirmed that this works)
- Then, as a part of `componentDidMount` of one of my root components, I have a listener for changes to the Firebase Database:

```
    var props = this.props

    function updateStateData(payload, props) {
        props.syncFirebaseToState(payload);
        }

    function syncWithFirebase(uid, props) {
        var syncStateWithFirebaseListener = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/userData");
        syncStateWithFirebaseListener.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            var localState = snapshot.val();
            updateStateData(localState, props);
            });
        }
```

- and `this.props.syncFirebaseToState(payload)` is a Redux action with this reducer:

`return { ...state, data: action.payload, loading: false };`

- which then confirms that the data has been written to the Firebase Realtime Database, and then takes down the loading page, letting the user know that their update is now safe.

For most cases, this flow works fine. However, I run into problems when the user has a bad internet connection or if I refresh the page too fast. For example:

- User loads app.
- Disconnects from internet.
- Submits data.
- Full loop works immediately and `loading:false` (Firebase Realtime Database wrote it in 'offline mode' and is waiting to be reconnected to the internet)
- User reconnects online.
- Once online, user immediately refreshes the page (reloading the React app)
- Firebase Realtime Database didn't have time to sync the queued updates to the remote database, and now after page refresh, the edits don't make it.

Sometimes, the user doesn't have to lose their internet connection. If they submit an edit (the page instantly returns a 'successful read') and then refresh before the remote server writes it down, the data is loss after the refresh is complete.

Anyway, as you can see, this is a really bad user experience. I really need a way to confirm that the data has actually been written to Firebase before removing the loading screen. I feel like I must be doing something wrong here and somehow getting a successful callback when it isn't.

This is my first time using React/Redux/Saga/Firebase, so I appreciate the patience and the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable offline mode.

I am assuming you don't want to do that so the next thing is to add a condition to check if your update is coming from the cache or the database.

Firebase Realtime Database provides a special location at `/.info/connected` which is updated every time the Firebase Realtime Database client's connection state changes. Here is an example:

```
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");
  } else {
    alert("not connected");
  }
});
```

You can then run this check alongside your update to turn to load off and then propagate the change depending on whether it's coming from cache or the actual database.